# Python_Flask_Webapp Select menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, flask

I'm learning Flask Web Development this book, I have a function on my page that in the "account" there is a select menu , I can choose the function inside , i.e. change password , or log out.
But it's strange that the select menu doesn't work in the index page, no response when I click the "account" , in others page , for example , below /user/AllenXu page , it works normally .

```
http://localhost:5000/user/AllenXu
```

[image: other pages]

**But in my index page, u can see it doesn't work.**

[image: index page]

What is confusing me is that the select menu code was setting in the base.html which is extends from **bootstrap** template , and other pages extends from the base.html , so actually it should work in every page which extends from base.html.

And actually it does work in `http://localhost:5000/user/AllenXu`

But why it does not work in index page ?

Below is my code information

**base.html**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
{% endblock %}





{% block navbar %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('main.index')}}">Flasky</a>
    </div>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="{{url_for('main.index')}}">Home</a></li>

    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=current_user.username) }}">Profile</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img src="{{ current_user.gravatar(size=18) }}">
                        Account <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.change_password') }}">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.change_email_request') }}">Change Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Log In</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
<div class="container">
    {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

**My views.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import render_template,session,redirect,url_for,flash
from . import main
from .forms import NameForm,EditProfileForm,EditProfileAdminForm,PostForm
from .. import db
from ..models import User,Role,Permission,Post
from flask.ext.login import login_required,current_user
from ..decorators import admin_required

@main.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = PostForm()
    if current_user.can(Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES) and form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(body = form.body.data,author = current_user._get_current_object())
        db.session.add(post)
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html',form = form, posts = posts)



@main.route('/user/<username>')
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
    if user is None:
        abort (404)
    return render_template('user.html',user = user)
    enter code here
```

**my index.html file**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}

{% block scripts %}          
{{ super() }}                 
{{ moment.include_moment() }}
{% endblock %}

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello,
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated%}
    {{ current_user.username }}
    {% else %}
    Stranger!
    {% endif %}
    </h1>
</div>

<div>
    {% if current_user.can(Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES) %}
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<ul class = "posts">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <li class = "post">
    <div class="profile-thumbnail">
        <a href = "{{ url_for('.user',username = post.author.username) }}">
            <img class = "img-rounded profile-thumbnail"
            src = "{{ post.author.gravatar(size = 40) }}">
        </a>
</div>

<div class="post-date">{{ moment(post.timestamp).fromNow() }}</div>
<div class="post-author">
    <a href = "{{ url_for('.user',username = post.author.username) }}">
    {{ post.author.username }}
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class = "post-body">{{ post.body }}</div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>   
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me !!
If any more information needed , please let me know

Comment: What about other pages?..like post, error pages?..can you see the drop down menu or can not?..

Comment: @IronFist Hello, til now I've only established these pages--- home page, user page, edit profile page,edit profile admin page, change password page...only in index page does not work... others work fine....

Comment: In your `{% block scripts %}` tag, is that where you're also loading the bootstrap .js files into the template? Reason I ask is because it's possible that your .js files are being loaded before all the HTML is rendered so the dropdown feature can't work properly. I also notice your index route has an option of allowing the `POST` method, but it doesn't look like you're using it. You should have something that has a `if request.method == 'POST':` to handle when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I just figured out the problem...I put the {block scripts} inside the {block content}... that made my super() function in the index page no use......But still thanks for your advice:)

Comment: @NoDinner Awesome! Glad you got it resolved! Best of luck on your app development!

Comment: @IronFist Ok got it. Sorry I'm a rookie here, thanks for reminder. And do u mean that add the answer in the question or add one more answer for it？

Comment: I mean, Post your findings as an answer to your question and accept it.

Comment: @IronFist Ok later when I am on PC I will post it with screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I found the problem which caused this...

because ...in my index.html , I insert the {%block scripts%} inside the {%block page_content%}....

the "block" should be seprarte...if block A is inside block B, the A is useless

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}
{% block page_content %}

{% block scripts %}          
{{ super() }}                 
{{ moment.include_moment() }}
{% endblock %}

<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello,
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated%}
    {{ current_user.username }}
    {% else %}
    Stranger!
    {% endif %}
    </h1>
</div>
```